# MVC4 Entity Framework - Cannot implicitly convert

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a Database using Entity Framework 5 from model.
This model have a table called 'Person', and another one called 'Administrator'.
'Administrator' inherits from 'Person'.

- 'Person' have an Id and a Name.
- 'Administrator' have Code.

Using MVC4 when I create a new Controller for 'Administrator'. When I create controller & views automatically this is the error:

Error 2 - Cannot implicitly convert type 'Model.Person' in 'Model.Administrator'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).

ERROR CODE (BETWEEN ASTERISKS):

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        **Administrator admin = db.Person.Single(u => u.Id == id);**
        if (admin == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(admin);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Administrator a = db.Person.OfType<Administrator>().Single(u => u.Id == id);
```

Use the [`OfType<>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) filter method that only returns objects that can be cast to that type. Or alternatively explicitly cast the object.

```
Administrator a = db.Person.Single(u => u.Id == id) as Administrator;
```

Both of these solutions will work.

Comment: @RobertPlant, I'm unfamiliar with the autogenerated files and whether you can configure them to account for inheritance like this.

Answer (score 1):

Even in MVC 5.1 the scaffold generation doesn't know how to handle inherited types.  You have to use the OfType<>() method to filter by object type like [bmused](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1914530/bmused) stated.

Also - you need to use the SingleOrDefault() extension method to be able to get a null returned if there are no records.  If you just use Single() and there are no records an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

> 'Administrator' inherits from 'Person'"

this mean an 'Administrator' is a 'Person' but a 'Person' may not be an 'Administrator'

you can have

```
Person p = new Administrator();
```

but

```
Administrator a = new Person();
```

is not correct and you need to make a cast.